# Does Gatsby support MongoDB relationships?

Tags: mongodb, graphql, gatsby

I am building a personal blog and chose Gatsby because of the obvious reasons(performance and easy to start out) and because I have some React background for the frontend. Also, I had built a simple app to create my content(html string) and store in a MongoDB database using express server. Now for the blog, I am just trying to pull the data from MongoDB using `gatsby-source-mongodb` plugin.

My MongoDB schemas have relationships. For instance, a 'Post' schema has a 'user' property which is an ObjectID that references a user from 'User' schema. My config for the `gatsby-source-mongodb` looks like:

```
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-source-mongodb',
      options: {
          dbName: 'KathaDB',
          collection: 'posts',
          server: {
              address: "somecluster",
              port: 27017
          },
          auth: {
              user: 'someuser',
              password: 'somepasswd'
          },
          extraParams: {
            replicaSet: 'test',
            ssl: true,
            authSource: 'admin',
            retryWrites: true,
            preserveObjectIds: true
        }

      }
  }
```

I have a couple of questions:

1. When I query, I get all the properties from my 'Post' schema but I don't have 'user' property in the response. I don't know if it is due to the type of the property. I dug up a bit and found a similar issue [here](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/11587). It seems like they have solved the issue by preserving the ObjectID but i didn't even get the property that is of type ObjectID.
2. Another thing, does this plugin support relationships? For example, is it possible to get the 'user' data when its ObjectID is given?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does.

MongoDB relies on ObjectIDs for relationships, so you might have to add `preserveObjectIds: true` to your plugin options:

```
{
  resolve: "gatsby-source-mongodb",
  options: {
    dbName: "KathaDB",
    collection: "posts",
    server: {
      address: "somecluster",
      port: 27017,
    },
    auth: {
      user: "someuser",
      password: "somepasswd",
    },
    extraParams: {
      replicaSet: "test",
      ssl: true,
      authSource: "admin",
      retryWrites: true,
      preserveObjectIds: true,
    },
    preserveObjectIds: true, // <= here
  },
};
```

I'm unsure whether `gatsby-source-mongodb` creates the relationships out of the box (I don't think it does, if my memory is correct), but with the `ObjectIds`, you can create foreign-key relationships using GraphQL.

There are two ways of doing this in Gatsby:

1. [Using mappings in `gatsby-config.js`](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/gatsby-config/#mapping-node-types)
2. [Using a GraphQL `@link` directive](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/schema-customization/#foreign-key-fields) through Gatsby's schema customization (from v2.2)

I recommend the second option, since it's a more GraphQL way of doing things, and happens in `gatsby-node.js` where most node operations are taking place. However, if you're starting out with Gatsby and GraphQL, the first option might be easier to set up.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I thought preserveObjectIds property in extraParams would do the trick.